# Find value from div where multiple divs with same name

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to find the value of TTM EPS from link https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/computers-software/infosys/IT

I wrote the following code:

```
import os
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
company = "Infosys"
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)   
driver.get("https://www.moneycontrol.com")
inputElement = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#form_topsearch>.txtsrchbox.FL')))
inputElement.send_keys(company, Keys.ENTER)         
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#proceed-button'))).click()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("oview_table")
```

Now, there are multiple classes with the same name "oview_table" and its table. How can I get the value of TTM EPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following `xpath` `//td[contains(text(),'TTM EPS')]/../td[contains(@class,'nseceps')]`
This is the lement you are looking for.
Now you can extract the text value  from it.
In order to get value of any other asset just pass it as a parameter to this string

Comment: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: The `xpath` I gave you is correct. You can verify it in F12 tool on the page. Maybe you just using it incorrect? it should be `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'TTM EPS')]/../td[contains(@class,'nseceps')]")`, not `find_element_by_class_name`

Comment: Thank you @Prophet for kind help

Answer (score 1):

This xpath should also work. Pass in the text you are looking for.

```
//div[@class='oview_table']//td[contains(normalize-space(.), 'TTM EPS')]
```

Comment: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: a = driver.find_element_by_class_name("//div[@class='oview_table']//td[contains(normalize-space(.), 'TTM EPS')]")

Comment: Sure! It's `xpath`, not `class name`! You have you use `find_element_by_xpath`. See my comment under my answer.